# Add a Xamarin.Forms macOS project to a solution on a PC

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

Is there any way to add a Xamarin.Forms macOS project to a solution on Visual Studio on a PC? I already have a solution with projects for iOS etc. Can I add macOS to the solution?

I've found an answer [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127947/can-i-add-a-macos-project-in-visual-studio-2017-for-windows) that seems to say that's impossible. But I think the answer's reasoning is wrong. Of course we'll need the Mac to build the app, but that's the case with iOS as well and it ***is*** possible to use it on a PC by connecting it to a Mac.

(And by the way, does anyone have any idea if macOS is production-ready?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements) gives you the answer. Unfortunately, it's not possible to fully work on Visual Studio like you do with iOS projects:

> Xamarin.Mac projects (macOS desktop apps) can be opened in Visual Studio and compiled to check for errors, but Mac applications cannot currently be built for distribution in Visual Studio.

Also, the [release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/#Xamarin.Mac_minimum_support.) of Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.2 states the following:

> Xamarin for Visual Studio has gained minimum support for Xamarin.Mac. This release enables Visual Studio to load and recognize Xamarin.Mac projects as supported. However, this minimum support allows only to build Xamarin.Mac projects without using the native Mac tool chain. The build process is performed locally on Windows, generating IL assemblies that cannot be used for running or debugging apps, and it doesn't create application bundles.

We're currently at the version 4.11 and there hasn't been any news since 4.2 about extended support for macOS projects. For now, you'll have to do with minimum support.

Comment: Thanks! What a pity, adding macOS to UWP, Android, and iOS Xamarin.Forms apps would really be nice.

Comment: You're welcome! I'd also like to have proper support for macOS but hopefully it's in the pipeline for the next major version.